# Using sed to replace the matching part of a line

Tags: regex, sed

I have this line in a test.txt file. And I just want to replace part of it, which is  "location="http://adcgen07.us.oracle.com:7777/". The whole line is:

```
    <soap:address xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" location="http://adcgen07.us.oracle.com:7777/soa-infra/services/default/TestProducer1/client"/>
```

The regular expression I wrote for the matching string is

```
    \blocation="http\b.*\b:777[0-9]
```

But if I use sed to replace the string, it will give me this following error.

```
    sed -i .bak 's/\blocation="http\b.*\b:777[0-9]/hello/' test.txt
    sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have forgotten a slash at the end : `sed -i .bak 's/\blocation="http\b.*\b:777[0-9]/hello/' test.txt`

Comment: Thanks. But if I added the slash at the end, I still got the same error.

Comment: You need to remove the space between `-i` and `.bak`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i ".bak" "s/location=\"http:\/\/.*:777[0-9]/hello/" test.txt
```